# URL rename not showing on Browser

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I change my **URL** name using **mod write**. But my **URL** doesn't show the changes on browser.

This is how it looks from before and after

**www.mydomain.com/toy/image.php**

to this

**www.mydomain.com/toy/xbox**

How can I make this: **www.mydomain.com/toy/xbox** appear on the browser

Another words on my website it should appear **www.mydomain.com/toy/xbox** instead of this 
**www.mydomain.com/toy/image.php**

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^toy/xbox$ /toy/image.php* [L,R]
```

Can someone to explain to me how it works. Did I missed a step? Do I need to used **PHP**?

If I did make a mistake, correct me so I can learn from my mistakes. I try to google this but I couldn't find what I need to do

Any links or explanations would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to "show the URL," you need it to do a 301/302 redirect, with a location header.  All you have to do is end your `RewriteRule` line with `[L,R=301]`

Comment: @landons. Thanks for the reply. I think I forgot to show my code with it. I do have it as R but not R=301. I will try that.

Comment: @landons. When you mention location header you mean something like this: header("Location: www.mydomain.com/toy/xbox"); will this appear on the browser? I try it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the `R=301` flag should set a location header (similar to the PHP method you mention).  After a redirect, the browser will show the new URL (it's not just an internal rewrite).  You must have something else going on... maybe try disabling other rewrite rules?

Comment: @landons. I did disable other. It kept saying: This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. How do I resolve that? I google it and try some methods of enabling cookie on the browser to have it so I can see the new URL. But it doesn't work. Do you know any tutorial regarding about url changes and dealing with cookies? Apparently you are correct when you mention something is going on. I just need to figure out the cookie issue maybe I can see the new URL. What do you mean when you mention an internal rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

You must perform a redirect using the `R` flag instead of just a rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ... ... [R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have what you mention but it doesn't work maybe I did it wrong. Plus I forgot to post my code for that.